# How to override/replace GWT class in Maven project?

Tags: java, maven, gwt, maven-3

I want to make some changes in `AbstractCellTable class` (change visibility of some fields and methods to protected or public etc). I've cloned `AbstractCellTable.java` file, made changes in it and put it into my Eclipse project 'commons' (with same package name `com.google.gwt...`).

Some other GWT projects use `commons` project. They are in the same Eclipse workspace and use source dependency from `commons`. I can compile them and use replaced `AbstractCellTable class` using standard GWT Eclipse plugin.

The problem appears when I want to change my projects to Maven ones. There is no problem with installation of `commons` project (mvn clean install). Changed source file of `AbstractCellTable.java` appears in generated jar file. But when I'm compiling dependant projects I get compile errors. I don't have stacktrace now, but the reason of this problem lies in using by GWT compiler original version of `AbstractCellTable class`. Errors show that `commons.jar` has compile errors (sic!) even if was installed properly earlier.

I've already tried to change ordering of dependencies in `pom.xml`, but it doesn't work. I'm thinking about installing own version of `gwt-user.jar` in my repo, but it won't be easy, as GWT project don't rely on Maven.

Is there any better solution to replace original GWT classes?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit GWT files, You need to create a the file with same name and place it in the same package structure in your application as in gwt.

For example : **AbstractCellTable** is in **com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client** package in **gwt-user** jar. So you need to have the same package structure in your package.

Another way is to create your own maven module say **custom-gwt-user** and have **gwt-user** as its dependency. And again follow the *same package structure*. While adding a dependency in your entrypoint package, make sure you have mentioned gwt-user dependency under **plugins->plugin->dependencies->dependency** and add two dependencies of **custom-gwt-user** and **gwt-user** under **dependencies->dependency** and make sure your custom-gwt-user is first in the order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the deferred binding method to replace an existing class with a new class of your own.  In your module.gwt.xml file add lines similar to this:

```
<replace-with class="com.stuff.something.MyClss">
     <when-type-is class="com.google.gwt.user.client.pathtoclass.AbstractCellTable"/>
</replace-with>
```

Comment: This only works for classes which are created with GWT.create()